# Why default Model binder behaving differently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I am creating API in which has following url

```
/api/abc/?q=1&a=2&b=3&b=4
                  ^^^^^^^
```

**Input.cs**(class used in ModelBinding)

```
...
public string A { get; set; }
public string B { get; set; }
public string Q { get; set; }
...
```

I am using default ModelBinding of .NET, But problem with that is when I passed above url, following values are assigned to the property

```
obj.A = "2"   // here obj is object of Input class
obj.B = "3"
obj.Q = "1"
```

I am expecting `obj.B = "3,4"`(when I am doing Request.QueryString["b"], it giving output as "3,4"), but it is binding the first value only.

Why is this happening?(I don't know internals of default ModelBinding but I am guessing it somewhere using Request.QueryString for binding).

**Can anyone tell me why it is happening and How can I get "3,4" as obj.B value?**

My approach for getting "3,4" for B is

using custom Model Binder I have done following

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    object model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    var obj = model as Input;
    obj.B = Request.QueryString["b"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending multiple values for `B` which means that you need to make `B` a collection. Note the `DefaultModelBinder` binds the first matching name/value pair and ignores the rest if your property is not `IEnumerable`.

Change the property to

```
public IEnumerable<string> B { get; set; }
```

and it will contain both values (if you then actually want `3,4`, you can use `String.Join` on the array).